# I need help finding what set these pieces are from, AM 02066 and AM 02067

Tags: set-identification

I recently found a bag of pieces from an older set that I lost the instructions to, and I don't remember the set name.  The set was a blue plane, and the cockpit pieces say AM 02066 and AM 02067.  I put this set away in 2007 when someone threw it so it is old and I can't find it anywhere.

Comment: Those numbers sound like manufacturing timestamps and not part numbers.  Can you post pictures of what pieces you have?  But LEGO hasn't made many blue planes so is http://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?S=712-1#T=S&O={} the one?

Comment: No it isn't and it definitely was supposed to be a plane from ten years ago.  I don't know how to post a picture on this question though.

Comment: Can you give us anything else to work on? I can't find any blue planes made in the years 2003-2007 that look like matches.

Comment: Most lego sets that have numbers printed on them, the number matches the set number. Nothing turns up for those two numbers.

Comment: Do you see your set [here](http://brickset.com/sets/tag-Aircraft), [here](http://brickset.com/sets/tag-Jet-Aircraft) or [here](http://brickset.com/sets/tag-Propeller-Aircraft) ?

Answer (score 2):

The set you are referring to is Mega Bloks set# 9728, Blue Thunder.  Instructions can be found here: https://support.megabrands.com/media/playbooks/9728.pdf

[image]

[image]

Answer (score -1):

The set "[gold hunt](http://brickset.com/sets/8630-1/Gold-Hunt)" from Lego Agents contains a sizeable blue plane. Any chance that's it? It's from 2008, not 2007, but it's another blue plane that comes to mind.